# TypeError: isPassword is not a function

Tags: node.js

Estou com este erro: TypeError: isPassword is not a function.
Fiz várias buscas na net, encontrei semelhanças mas ainda não consegui resolver. Então de uma outra forma resolvi, mas como estou iniciando os estudos queria saber o pq não passa, onde posso estar errando em criar um classMethod e utilizar ele:

Criei este js:

```
import bcrypt from "bcrypt";

module.exports = (sequelize, DataType) => {
  const Users = sequelize.define("usuarios", {
    id: {
      type: DataType.INTEGER,
      primaryKey: true,
      autoIncrement: true
    },
    nome: {
      type: DataType.STRING,
      allowNull: false,
      validate: {
        notEmpty: true
      }
    },
    password: {
      type: DataType.STRING,
      allowNull: false,
      validate: {
        notEmpty: true
      },
      field : 'senha'
    },
    email: {
      type: DataType.STRING,
      unique: true,
      allowNull: false,
      validate: {
        notEmpty: true
      }
    },
    datacadastro: {
      type: DataType.DATE,
      defaultValue: new Date()
    }
  }, 
  {
      hooks: {
          beforeCreate: user => {
             const salt = bcrypt.genSaltSync();
             user.password = bcrypt.hashSync(user.password, salt);
          }
        },
      classMethods: {
          **//estou tendo erro em utilizar este isPassword**
          isPassword: (encodedPassword, password) => {
            return bcrypt.compareSync(password, encodedPassword);
          }
        }
  });
  return Users;
};
```

**Aqui neste token.js que será utilizado para validar o email e senha:**

```
import jwt from "jwt-simple";

module.exports = app => {
  const cfg = app.libs.config;
  const Users = app.db.models.usuarios;

  app.post("/token", (req, res) => {
    if (req.body.email && req.body.password) {
      const email = req.body.email;
      const password = req.body.password;
      Users.findOne({where: {email: email}})
        .then(user => {
          **//Na linha abaixo que acontece o erro citado**
          if (Users.isPassword(user.password, password)) {
            const payload = {id: user.id};
            res.json({
              token: jwt.encode(payload, cfg.jwtSecret)
            });
          } else {
            res.sendStatus(401);
          }
        })
        .catch(error => res.sendStatus(401));
    } else {
      res.sendStatus(401);
    }
  });
};
```

Comment: Primeiro de tudo, o que é o primeiro arquivo? Um arquivo que define o modelo para Users? Segundo, onde que você importa / requere o primeiro arquivo?

Comment: Exato desculpe se não expliquei muito bem, mas é isto mesmo.

Comment: Ja tentou definir o metodo de classe assim: `const Users = ...; Users.isPassword = ...; return Users`

Comment: Desculpe a ignorância mas como estou iniciando em node js não tentei não:   if (Users.methods.isPassword(user.password, password)) { .. seria assim que disse para eu tentar deu erro: TypeError: Cannot read property 'isPassword' of undefined

Comment: Comenta tudo dentro da callback do then. Defina uma funcao qualquer que de um console log, por exemplo, como eu disse antes. Depois de definir Users com sequelize.define(), é so falar `Users.qualquerFuncao = () => console.log('qualquerFuncao!!');` Ai dentro da callback que eu mencionei no comeco, chama a funcao de classe: `Users.qualquerFuncao()`. Se isso funcionar, entao seu problema estara resolvido.

Comment: Valeu amigo encontrei uma forma de resolver, com sua ajuda e dicas encontrei um link sobre sequelize que mostrar como migrar e o que mudou de uma versão para outra, como disse estou no começo peguei um tutorial para aprender pois não me atentei as versões das frameworks.

Comment: Eh sempre bom mencionar a versao da ferramenta e sempre ler a documentacao que se refere a tal versao. Isso acontece muito quando a versao principal muda de uma para outra.

Answer (score 1):

A quem possa interessar eu encontrei o pq deste erro neste link:

http://docs.sequelizejs.com/manual/tutorial/upgrade-to-v4.html

Em resumo é diferença de versão do sequelize o User.js (model) ficou assim:

```
import bcrypt from "bcrypt";

module.exports = (sequelize, DataType) => {
  const Users = sequelize.define("usuarios", {
    id: {
      type: DataType.INTEGER,
      primaryKey: true,
      autoIncrement: true
    },
    nome: {
      type: DataType.STRING,
      allowNull: false,
      validate: {
        notEmpty: true
      }
    },
    password: {
      type: DataType.STRING,
      allowNull: false,
      validate: {
        notEmpty: true
      },
      field : 'senha'
    },
    email: {
      type: DataType.STRING,
      unique: true,
      allowNull: false,
      validate: {
        notEmpty: true
      }
    },
    datacadastro: {
      type: DataType.DATE,
      defaultValue: new Date()
    }
  }, {
    hooks: {
      beforeCreate: user => {
        const salt = bcrypt.genSaltSync();
        user.password = bcrypt.hashSync(user.password, salt);
      }
   }
 });

  Users.isPassword = (encodedPassword, password) => {
    return bcrypt.compareSync(password, encodedPassword);
  }

  return Users;
};
```

Comment: Entao voce ta usando a versao 4, mas tinha usado definicoes para uma versao antiga? Se puder, por favor adicione que versao voce usou na sua questao. Obrigado!

Comment: Pois é eu estava seguindo um tutorial e não me atentei a versão, vacilei, como disse iniciando estudos e a versão do sequelize: 4.4.2